# Extracting values of a cell while looping

Tags: excel, vba

I have two cells, let's call them `B16` and `C29`. `C29` is dependent on `B16` through some complex calculations and macros. I wish to know how `C29` changes by looping `B16` through different values. How can I do this through VBA or a macro?

```
Sub Theta()
Dim theta_list As Variant, t As Double, V(101, 1) As Double


theta_list = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BI2:BI102")

For i = 1 To 101:
    t = theta_list(i, 1)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B16").Value = t
    Call Converty
    V(i, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C29").Value
Next i

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BJ2:BJ102") = V
    

End Sub
```

I tried with the macro above but `V` just spits out a list of zeros. When I run this macro on the spreadsheet I see `B16` and `C29` change through the loop, but my `V` in the program is not capturing the value of `C29` as it changes. Could you help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: You should preface each range object with it's parent sheet: `WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("BI2:BI102")` and so on.  My guess is that your code ends up looking at the wrong sheet.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you for the response. I only have one worksheet. Nonetheless I added Worksheets as you suggested and `V` only spits back zeros still. I tried adding a MsgBox right under `Call Converty` and it is notifying me of the new `C29` value everytime, but somehow `V` is not storing them. Could it be something to do with the declaration of `V`? I am not super familiar with Excel datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

`V(101, 1)` is the same as `V(0 to 101, 0 to 1)` so that declaration is not going to allow you to use the array as you want.

You probably want something more like this:

```vb
Sub Theta()
    
    Dim theta_list As Variant, t As Double, V() As Double, i As Long
    
    theta_list = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E102")
    ReDim V(1 To UBound(theta_list, 1), 1 To UBound(theta_list, 2))
    
    For i = 1 To 101
        t = theta_list(i, 1)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B16").Value = t
        'Call Converty
        V(i, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C29").Value
    Next i
    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Resize( _
         UBound(theta_list, 1), UBound(theta_list, 2)).Value = V
        
End Sub
```